# OAuth 2.0 not getting authorized

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, console-application

I'm writing a console application in C# which should connect to a website that uses OAuth 2.0.

I'm using the following code :

```
var client = new RestClient(new Uri(BaseUri, "api/oauth2/Token"));
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + user.RefreshToken);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + MyClientIdentifier() + "&client_secret=" + MyClientSecret(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

When I'm running the code I keep getting the StatusCode

> Unauthorized

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what you hold in user.RefreshToken, but RefreshToken can not be used for authorization/authentication.

Comment: From the website where I want to create my connection, I got an AccessToken and a RefreshToken. Both of them I stored in my database. I want to go to a different page/method on the providing website and I thought I could do that by passing my credentials as above.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using http://restsharp.org/

Comment: @Jodrell indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong `grant_type` for a refresh token, [here is the relevant specification](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/), so the following code should work, if your parameters are valid.

```
var client = new RestClient(new Uri(BaseUri, "api/oauth2/Token"));
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "grant_type=refresh_token" +
        $"&refresh_token={user.RefreshToken}" +
        $"&client_id={MyClientIdentifier()}" + 
        $"&client_secret={MyClientSecret()}",
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: When I use the grant_type=refresh I still get the "Unauthorized"

Comment: Hmm, in my code, all the parameters are in the body, not as headers

Comment: When I use the code you have in your answer, I get the "Unauthorized"

Comment: @BartSchelkens I edited again but perhaps you need `AddBody` instead of `AddParameter`.

Comment: @BartSchelkens this is the relevant part of the spec https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

Comment: @BartSchelkens I think I missed the `_token` off the `grant_type`.

Comment: I have one more question. Now it works fine. I want to get more information from the providing website. So I performed the above code, thinking I was authorized now. But when I post my second request I get the message "Unauthorized"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192367/discussion-between-bart-schelkens-and-jodrell).